# can i change all column values according to master table in oracel forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I am creating POS in oracle 11g. in the sale form i have two master and child table,one column is 'type' who is exist in those table, child table is in table mode has 10 rows.
now i what to know is it possible that after inserting 10 rows in child table  when i change 'type' in master table then also change all values in child table according to master table.
i am trying list item in master table but it's only change current values of child table. how can i change all values in child table.

Answer (score 1):

The way you put it, there are two options.

If changes are committed (i.e. both master and detail rows are stored into the database), you could update detail rows as

```
update detail_table d set
  d.type = :master_block.type
  where d.foreign_key_column = :master_block.primary_key_item;
```

and then requery the detail block as

```
go_block('detail_block');
execute_query;
```

---

Another is to loop through the detail block and modify items row-by-row:

```
go_block('detail_block');
first_record;
loop
  :detail_block.type := :master_block.type;
  exit when :system.last_record = 'true';
  next_record;
end loop;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have put script in 'when-list-change' trigger on detail_block.type.
but when i change list block goes hang.
 go_block('detail_block');
first_record;
loop
  :detail_block.type := :master_block.type;
  exit when :system.last_record = 'true';
  next_record;
end loop;

Comment: You're welcome. I made a mistake; TRUE should be enclosed into single quotes (fixed now), but I presume you already fixed it, otherwise the form wouldn't compile. Code I posted should be somewhere in the MASTER block, not detail. If you want to use master block's TYPE value in the DETAIL block (for newly added rows), then modify detail block TYPE column's DEFAULT value to :MASTER_BLOCK.TYPE.

Comment: No something wrong in trigger. form goes freeze after fire the trigger.
i think the problem is in 'exit when :system.last_record = 'true'  loop not stopping with this command

Comment: Debug it, then, and see what's going on.